# Protractor tests in headless environment without browser installation

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

I face the problem with running protractor tests in headless environment. I know about option with **Chrome**, which implies setting up like that:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu" ]
    }
}
```

However when using this method, I am obliged to have Chrome installed on my system which isn't option for me because I can't be sure about environment which my tests will be run in. PhantomJS would be great in my case, because everything you need is just install npm package. But PhantomJS in deprecated at the moment and can cause some unexpected bugs. 
So my question is: **Is there any way to use headless Chrome or some other alternative (like PhantomJS) which won't oblige me to install any browser?**

Thank you for your time.